# Fill Multiple Tables in Single Typed Dataset?

Tags: c#, strongly-typed-dataset

Background

I am new to working with Datasets. I am finding examples, reading how-tos, watching tutorials, trying things to break down information and build it back up again to gain an understanding. I have the following:

```
GPDataSetTableAdapters.VPF_WORKTableAdapter adapt_VPF_WORK = new GPDataSetTableAdapters.VPF_WORKTableAdapter();
GPDataSetTableAdapters.VPF_Exhibitor_MSTRTableAdapter adapt_VPF_Exhibitor = new GPDataSetTableAdapters.VPF_Exhibitor_MSTRTableAdapter();
GPDataSet ds1 = new GPDataSet();
GPDataSet ds2 = new GPDataSet();

adapt_VPF_WORK.Fill(ds1.VPF_WORK);
adapt_VPF_Exhibitor.Fill(ds2.VPF_Exhibitor_MSTR);
```

Question

My question comes from noticing that each dataset variable shows me the other tables in the dataset:

```
ds1.VPF_Exhibitor_MSTR
```

...but the dataset was filled with a table adapter specific to one table. So is there a way to use a table adapter from the typed dataset to fill every table so that I am free to eliminate the need for the ds2 variable and use only ds1 with every table in my dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - just use the same dataset reference in each `Fill`:

```
GPDataSetTableAdapters.VPF_WORKTableAdapter adapt_VPF_WORK = new GPDataSetTableAdapters.VPF_WORKTableAdapter();
GPDataSetTableAdapters.VPF_Exhibitor_MSTRTableAdapter adapt_VPF_Exhibitor = new GPDataSetTableAdapters.VPF_Exhibitor_MSTRTableAdapter();
GPDataSet ds1 = new GPDataSet();
//GPDataSet ds2 = new GPDataSet();

adapt_VPF_WORK.Fill(ds1.VPF_WORK);
adapt_VPF_Exhibitor.Fill(ds1.VPF_Exhibitor_MSTR);   // <-- change ds2 to ds1
```

Comment: I love the simple answers that make one feel stupid for not even thinking of the method. Thank you.